# Jenkins Configure Page not "LOADING" ,version:1.651.3, Chrome browser

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins started using this command:

```
java -jar .\jenkins.war.
```

After this I hit the URL local host:8080.

2. Create the project, Start window as service.
3. Add some performance plugins from this same page "Manage Jenkins"---->"Available plugins" section.
4. Now click on configure for this project in chrome browser.
5. Page not loading, even if after so many refresh activity, page comes in IE browser but freeze showing "Loading" onto the page.

Comment: Please Help me on this. let me know if any input required

Comment: Did you try disabling the all the plugins you installed and then going to configure?

Comment: @Mobrockers , no I have not disable the plugins. Cause I want to see the “Publish Performance Test Result Report” option under Jenkins -> Your Project -> Configure -> “Add post-build action” dropdown.

Comment: I have added Performance Plugin 1.13,Performance Publisher plugin 8.04,Performance Signature with Dynatrace 2.1.2.

Comment: And what if one of your plugins contains a bug that makes your configure page not open..? First thing you do when trying to fix an error is disabling anything non-standard. Then you can re-enable your plugins one by one to see if one of them caused it.

Comment: @Thank you Mobrockers. I  Have successfully ran it with only Performance plugins 1.13

Comment: Then I suggest you file an issue with the plugin that was causing the problem, so they can fix it for you.

Comment: I have the same issue. While most of the time the config page loads immediately, sometime it is "loading" forever, but if I click "reload" it loads immediately